# Search and replace alphanumeric characters with empty string in python

Tags: python, python-re

My apology if this post is duplicate. I attempted to use `import re` from `python` to `search/replace` a word. From below example, I want to locate `aaa1` only and replace it with `empty string`.

```
# Input case 1
str = 'aaa,aaa1,aaa1.1'

# Input case 2
str = 'aaa,aaa1'

# Expected output for the case 1
'aaa,aaa1.1'

# Expected output for the case 2
'aaa'
```

I tried word boundary `\b`, to be honest I am confused with what it is + how to use it properly (https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
re.sub(r'\baaa1\b', '', str)
```

The result is `aaa,,.1` as some of you already expected. I tried with `/^aaa1$/` also but no luck. I am new to `python` and its module such as `re`. I'd appreciate your advice on how to pull ^ objective.

[update]

I updated my original question with inputs and expected outputs for the clarification of my objective.

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: `aaa,aaa1.1` as output sire.

Comment: Are you looking for `re.sub(r'\baaa1,', '', str)` ?

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately I was getting same output I posted.

Comment: Please take a closer look. I'm including the comma inside the regex. So, the substring `aaa1.` won't be replaced.

Comment: My apology. I missed that ','. Your suggestion works for me.

Comment: @DaeYoung I edited my answer so it works for you edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
def filter_str(s):
    s = re.sub(r'\baaa1,', '', s)
    return re.sub(r',aaa1$', '', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
def f(str):
    s = str.split(',')
    if 'aaa1' in s:
        for n in s:
            if n == 'aaa1': s.remove(n)
        return(','.join(s))
    else:
        for n in s:
            if 'aaa1' in n: s.remove(n)
        return(','.join(s))

print(f('aaa,aaa1,aaa1.1'))
print(f('aaa,aaa1.1'))
```

Output:

```
aaa,aaa1.1
aaa
```

Comment: Ty for your advice. I have tried that earlier but I was getting ^ output as you posted.

Comment: what do you mean ^? Oh, i see.

Comment: I was hoping to get `aaa,aaa1.1` instead after removing `aaa1`.

Comment: Your suggestion definitely works for me. I appreciate your time. I could accept your solution as an answer but I was hoping to solve with `regex` as much as possible. Ty for expanding my little understanding on `python`.